# Grails Hibernate H2 problem

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, h2

I have an application with two domain classes as follows:

> DomainA : PK, name
>
> DomainB : PK, FK (points to
>   DomainA.PK), name.

And when I try to list elements that belongs to DomainA using the DomainB.name as order factor, as follows:

```
def listings DomainA.createCriteria().list(params) {
  PK{
     order('name','asc')
  }
}
```

This works with mysql but not with H2 giving me the next error:

> Column DomainB.name must be in the
>   GROUP BY list; SQL statement:

So Itried the next solution without lucky:

```
def listings DomainA.createCriteria().list(params) {
  projections{
     groupProperty('name')
  }
  PK{
     order('name','asc')
  }
}
```

Any Ideas or solutions to this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been bitten by the same problem, it seems is a bug in H2: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8162

Answer (score 0):

You can always fall back to an HQL query instead of using criteria.